# Observable.Interval only fires for the first instance

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, monogame

I'm trying to use Reactive Extensions with MonoGame. I don't know if this is new or anybody has tried before me, but I'm getting mixed results.

My scenario is the following. I have a bunch of `SpaceShips` that drop a bomb every 2 seconds. This is what I do:

```
class SpaceShip
{
    private IDisposable bombDropper;
    public SpaceShip()
    {
        bombDropper = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                if (Top + Height + 20 < Constants.GroundTop)
                {
                    Stage.AddRelative(new Bomb(), this, RelativePosition.Bottom);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The problem is that only the first SpaceShip drops bombs. Why? Every instance of `SpaceShip` is different, and each one has its very own observable, but only the first is firing events!

Somebody told me this:

> I’m a little suspicious about your dispatcher not being updated or
>   blocking on the same thread of the dispatcher not sure if mono game
>   would have a dispatcher dispatcher tends to be a very Windows thing

So my question is: how can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue! Guess what? it wasn't related to the SpaceShip itself, but with the way they are generated!

```
enemyAdder = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Subscribe(_ => this.Add(new Ship()
            {
                Top = Utils.Random.Next((int) Constants.GroundTop),
                Left = width, 
            }));
```

this subscription generated space ships every 3 seconds, but for some reason, I forgot the `ObserveOn` part.

This is the fixed version:

```
enemyAdder = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher).Subscribe(_ => this.Add(new Ship()
            {
                Top = Utils.Random.Next((int) Constants.GroundTop),
                Left = width, 
            }));
```

With the ObserveOn, it works! I wonder why it worked without it. Maybe I was just lucky.